# Linear Algebra Library

Tags: c#, c++, python

Where can I find similar function as [`numpy.linalg.norm`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html) (Python) for C++ or C#? This function is able to return one of seven different matrix norms, or one of an infinite number of vector norms, depending on the value of the `ord` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your platform and the depth of your pocket you might be interested in [Intel's MKL](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-intel-mkl-in-your-c-program/) which is callable from both C++ and C#

Answer (score 0):

See if this library makes sense for you:

[Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You can compile [blas](http://www.netlib.org/blas/) and [lapack](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) with a Fortran Compiler and link against them in your C++ Program.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [alglib](http://www.alglib.net/matrixops/rcond.php) is appropriate for you?

Answer (score 0):

For C# the numerics part of the Math.NET project may be what you want.

http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vector2.Length()
Example:

```
using System.Numerics;

namespace LinearAlgebraCSharp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Vector2 vec1 = new Vector2(2, 3);

            // Equivalent of <numpy.linalg.norm>
            float vectorModule = vec1.Length();
        }
    }
}
```